# i want to fetch the data from csv in sequential order in jmeter.What should be done?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

In jmeter i have to read the data from csv using csv data config sequentially.could anyone please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use one thread then it is sequential, but for multiple each thread will pick up different line of data. Check below information:-

> By default, the file is only opened once, and each thread will use a
>   different line from the file. However the order in which lines are
>   passed to threads depends on the order in which they execute, which
>   may vary between iterations. Lines are read at the start of each test
>   iteration. The file name and mode are resolved in the first iteration.

If you need that each thread should run with the same data set and in sequence then change the sharing mode to current thread.

If you want all request to follow a particular order and fetch that data in sequence then use [critical section controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller).

> The Critical Section Controller ensures that its children elements
>   (samplers/controllers, etc.) will be executed by only one thread as a
>   named lock will be taken before executing children of controller.

But in all cases, next line will be picked up on the next iteration of a particular thread.

Answer (score 1):

With multiple threads, split the csv equal to number of threads and in csv data config along with the filename attached the thread num function as ${__threadNum} and post that once you execute your run, the thread will pick there file individually.